# An open $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R$ with $V=E\cap\Omega$ and $U\subset\Omega^c$, where $U,V$ are relatively open and separate $E\subseteq\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

The following statement comes from page 253 of the book *An Introduction to Analysis*, 3rd. ed., by  William R. Wade.

> ***8.38 THEOREM**. Let $E\subseteq R^{n}$. If there exist nonempty, relatively open sets $U,V$ which separate $E$, then there is a pair of open sets $A,B$ such that $A\cap E\ne \emptyset$, $B\cap E\ne\emptyset$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, and $E\subseteq A\cup B$.
>
> PROOF. We first show that $$\qquad\qquad\qquad \overline U\cap V=\emptyset. \tag{9}$$
>   Indeed, since $V$ is relatively open in $E$, there is a set $\Omega$, open in $R^{n}$, such that $V=E\cap\Omega$. Since $U\cap V=\emptyset$, it follows that $\color{red}{U\subset \Omega^{c}}$. This last set is closed in $R^n$.
>
> Therefore, $$\overline U \subseteq  \overline{\Omega^{c}}=\Omega^{c},$$
>   i.e. (9) holds.

---

My question is why $\color{red}{U\subset \Omega^{c}}$? It is obvious that  $U\subseteq V^{c}$, but we cannot be sure $U\subset \Omega^{c}$. So I think $U\subset \Omega^{c}$ is a plain clerical error. And then, if $U\subset \Omega^{c}$ does not hold, how to prove (9) holds?

Comment: It is not an error. If $ x \in U \cap \Omega $, then $ x \in E $ since $ U \subset E $. Then $ x \in V $ since $ \Omega \cap E = V $. This contradicts disjointness of $ U $ and $ V$.

Comment: @user226970:Thanks,it was a mistake of mine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly we have $U, V \subseteq E$ (otherwise the step does not necessarily hold). Thus
$$
 U \cap \Omega
 = (U \cap E) \cap \Omega
 = U \cap (E \cap \Omega)
 = U \cap V
 = \emptyset,
$$
which means that $U \subseteq \Omega^c$.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I make such silly mistakes.

Comment: Don’t worry, we’ve all been there.